# How to add headers to assets for cache validation?

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, caching, http-headers, service-worker

I've been googling and testing stuff for the past couple of days but unfortunately I cant find a solution for my problem...

---

I am working on a Symfony 2 application that uses a Service-Worker to cache a bunch of assets. For whatever reason I can't seem to add headers like ETag or Expires to the assets for a custom cache validation.

I am using PHP's built-in Web Server, so my initial thought was to add this piece of code to the htaccess file(s)*, because the assets are served by the server. It didnt work.

 * ***web/.htaccess, app/.htaccess, src/.htaccess***

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive On
   ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
   ExpiresByType text/js "access 1 week"
   ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 week"
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong? Looking at the response headers, they still look the same:

```
Connection:close
Content-Length:6133
Content-Type:text/css; charset=UTF-8
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
```

Should I configure the server to handle this kind of stuff? 
If so, what file and what data should I use?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the php server documentation it seems that this server only returns a minimal set of http headers, unlike apache. Which means I need to switch server in order to solve my problem.